# ssl connection error: unknown error number

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

Using MySQL Workbench Ver. 6.3.6

As of an update just pushed to my Google SQL db instance I can no longer connect to the db with Workbench..   I receive the following error when I do.

```
ssl connection error: unknown error number
```

Anyone else experiencing this?   Know a fix?

So far I have found only one person in google groups reporting the same issue a just 2 days back.

P.S. My second instance in Google SQL has NOT updated yet, and I can still connect to it.

P.S.S. I'm not using SSL connections even.

**UPDATE**

5 Back to back Updates by google in the last 30 minutes.    Somethings definitely up.. but sadly I still can't connect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The latest update to Google SQL makes MySQL Workbench 6.3.6 no longer able to connect.

Updating to 6.3.9 fixed it for me.

[Download Latest MySQL WorkBench Here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Comment: Below is a separate discussion reaffirming this:      https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-sql-discuss/4CzuZmMwYM4/ksc16PJJCQAJ

Comment: Thank you for saving a lot of time here. They should implement a better error message for that...

Comment: LOL spent a day and all i needed was update the workbench, thx!

Comment: This helped me. Updating the version works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but it seems to be something with MySQL workbench. I downloaded heidisql and can connect using the same credentials. The MySQL workbench connection worked a week ago.

Comment: I can still connect to the DB from command line and java connectors and such..   Yes it is limited to MySQL it seems.. My searching found this error came up many years and versions ago with Workbench but was then fixed...    Seems it is back??

Comment: What version Workbench you using?

Comment: Not sure if it's back. I am using 6.3.6

Comment: Try the latest (6.3.9 atm).

Comment: Welp it is 100% for sure have to do with the update... They updated my second DB at midnight.. now I can't connect to it any more.. downloading 6.3.9 to try now.

Comment: I am on 6.3.9 and still having this issue. Only with connecting to gen 1

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened at my end yesterday, I installed the latest on Windows and it worked. On my Mac, updating to 3.6.8 fixed the issue.

Download link: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the docker container and running mysql workbench as administrator worked for me
127.0.0.1
3306
root